# Javascript - Drag and Select ability

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag, multi-select

I'm looking for functionality to allow a user to mousedown and drag to select multiple items.  The action would be essentially what you see in the Mac Finder or Windows Explorer.

This might be a duplicate of [JavaScript Drag & Select functionality done right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851156/javascript-drag-select-functionality-done-right) and the answer http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop/demo/selection is decent, but a little buggy.

Anyone know of any good solutions?

Comment: I should have looked around a bit more. Jquery UI Selectable is what I was looking for http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/

Comment: Make you sure you put that as your answer and mark it as accepted.