# Identify user-highlighted images on a page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, jquery-events

If I have an html page with a number of images displayed, and a user drag-selects several images (i.e. highlights them as selected) with a mouse, can I identify those images via JavaScript or otherwise?

In other words, the use-case is that I want to "tag" multiple images at once and allow a user to use a mouse to click anywhere on the screen, then hold the mouse button down while moving the mouse, creating a highlighted rectangle, thus selecting all items displayed on the page within that rectangle. The goal is then to identify only images that were selected, and present a pop-up to the user, allowing her to "tag" those highlighted images.

Sorry if this is confusing, I'm just not sure what the common terminology is to describe what I want.

Comment: Use an onclick function on every image. Give the images a common class name and add an onclick handler for that class. Give the images a unique id.

Comment: Have a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5851237/844726

Comment: Thanks guys! That link is exactly it, thanks swatkins!

Comment: FYI, here's another good example: http://words.transmote.com/wp/20130714/jqueryui-draggable-selectable/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript Drag & Select functionality done right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851156/javascript-drag-select-functionality-done-right)